# Listar Json em um Select com Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Não estou conseguindo listas os dados de um Json em um Select

Meu código Jquery está assim:

```js
$("#cidades").change(function () {
            var options_escolas = ''; 
            var cidade = $("#cidades").val();   
    $.ajax({ url: 'api_escolas.php/?cidade='+cidade, 
       dataType: 'json', 
       crossDomain: true, 
           success: function (data) {   
                        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
         options_escolas += '<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>';
            }); 
        $("#escolas").html(options_escolas);
           }  
       });
  });
```

E o arquivo Json retornado é o seguinte:

```js
[
 9,
 [
  {
   "anoCenso": 2013,
   "cod": 52085163,
   "nome": "CENTRO MUNICIPAL DE EDUCACAO INFANTIL JOSE PEDRO DA COSTA",
   "codCidade": 5200050,
   "cidade": "ABADIA DE GOIAS",
   "estado": "GO",
   "regiao": "Centro-Oeste",
   "situacaoFuncionamento": 2,
   "dependenciaAdministrativa": 3,
   "idebAI": 0,
   "idebAF": 0,
   "enemMediaGeral": 0,
   "situacaoFuncionamentoTxt": "Paralisada",
   "dependenciaAdministrativaTxt": "Municipal"
  },
  {
   "anoCenso": 2013,
   "cod": 52098290,
   "nome": "CENTRO MUNICIPAL DE EDUCACAO INFANTIL SAINT CLAIR DE MENDONCA",
   "codCidade": 5200050,
   "cidade": "ABADIA DE GOIAS",
   "estado": "GO",
   "regiao": "Centro-Oeste",
   "situacaoFuncionamento": 1,
   "dependenciaAdministrativa": 3,
   "idebAI": 0,
   "idebAF": 0,
   "enemMediaGeral": 0,
   "situacaoFuncionamentoTxt": "Em atividade",
   "dependenciaAdministrativaTxt": "Municipal"
  },
  {
   "anoCenso": 2013,
   "cod": 52040127,
   "nome": "COLEGIO ESTADUAL MANOEL LIBANIO DA SILVA",
   "codCidade": 5200050,
   "cidade": "ABADIA DE GOIAS",
   "estado": "GO",
   "regiao": "Centro-Oeste",
   "situacaoFuncionamento": 1,
   "dependenciaAdministrativa": 2,
   "idebAI": 0,
   "idebAF": 4,
   "enemMediaGeral": 469.2380065917969,
   "situacaoFuncionamentoTxt": "Em atividade",
   "dependenciaAdministrativaTxt": "Estadual"
  }
 ]
]
```

E no select aparece somente o número 9. Preciso listar as escolas pelo nome.

Comment: Eu quero colocar nas opcoes do select os valores do "nome" CENTRO MUNICIPAL DE EDUCACAO INFANTIL JOSE PEDRO DA COSTA, CENTRO MUNICIPAL DE EDUCACAO INFANTIL SAINT CLAIR DE MENDONCA fazer um loop e listas as escolas.... eu tenho outro que pega as cidades que está funcionando bem com esse código, mas nesse json antes ele tras a quantidade de escolas, isso que está atrapalhando.

Answer (score 1):

O retorno é uma array onde as informações estão no segundo índice. Como você quer popular um `select` com essas informações, você pode pegar os objetos do segundo índice da array com `data[1]`. Em seguida acrescentar ao `val` o nome da chave que você que pegar:

```
$.each(data[1], function (key, val) {
   options_escolas += '<option value="' + val.cod + '">' + val.nome + '</option>';
});
```

No exemplo acima o `val.cod` irá pegar os valores em `cod:` e `val.nome` em `nome:` de cada bloco.

Comment: Deu certo obrigado !!!! esse negócio de segundo indice que não estava sabendo fazer, abracos

Comment: Bem-vindo ao site! [Veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) como que faz quando uma resposta é a correta para a sua pergunta. Abs!

Comment: @dvd só uma dúvida, quando usa `function (key, val)`, o que seria a `key` e o `val` ?

Comment: @JorgeMatheus `key` é o índice da array (0, 1 ,2...) e `val` o valor. Na verdade não precisa ter esse nome, poderia ser qualquer nome: `function(chave, valores)`, por exemplo... O 1º parâmetro é o índice, e o 2º o valor...

Answer (score 0):

O resultado fica no segundo item do array do retorno. 
Troca a linha para isso:

```
$.each(data[1], function (key, val) {
                        options_escolas += '<option value="' + val.nome + '">' + val.nome + '</option>';
```

Comment: Deu certo obrigado!